# Drop view syntax with dynamically generated view name

Tags: sql

I am working on a stored procedure where I have drop views with dynamically generated view names.

But there is some issue with my syntax it's throwing an error..

```
SET @vname = 'test.V_' + @sourceTable + '_Default';

IF OBJECT_ID(@vname) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW @vname; ---- this is where its throwing error
END;
```

Comment: Depends on your **RDBMS** you're using (please add a relevant tag!) - but most SQL dialects don't allow you to "parametrize" table and column names. In T-SQL (SQL Server) , you need to use **dynamic SQL** to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use dynamic SQL:

```
SET @vname = 'test.' +  QUOTENAME('V_'+ @sourceTable + '_Default');
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'DROP VIEW ' + @vname;

IF OBJECT_ID(@vname) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   EXEC(@sql); 
END;
```

If you have SQL Server 2016+ you could use `IF EXISTS`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS test.' + 
        QUOTENAME('V_' + @sourceTable + '_Default');
EXEC(@sql);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ae5909d9c1e1e6b18fa864c380b60d8)**